# Identifier must be declared with a port mode error in verilog

Tags: verilog

```
//3.v
module and3(x,y,z,w1,s);

input x,y,z;
wire w1;
output s;

assign w1=y&z;
assign s=w1|x;

endmodule
```

I got error here. "Identifier must be declared with a port mode error:w1". I searched similar errors but I think I declared it right. Or does my testbench wrong?

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module testbench;
reg x,y,z;
wire w1,s;

and3 and3(x,y,z,w1,s);

initial
begin
#250;x=0;y=0;z=0;
#250;x=0;y=0;z=1;
#250;x=0;y=1;z=0;
#250;x=0;y=1;z=1;
#250;x=1;y=0;z=0;
#250;x=1;y=0;z=1;
#250;x=1;y=1;z=0;
#250;x=1;y=1;z=1;
end

endmodule
```

How should I correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its telling you it wants the direction.

Like this:

```
module and3(x,y,z,w1,s);

input x,y,z;
output s,w1;

assign w1=y&z;
assign s=w1|x;

endmodule
```

Port defaults are confusing, better to specify and make the design intent clear.  Don't count on the reader of your code knowing all the default rules for type, kind, direction etc.

See
https://www.edaboard.com/threads/default-type-of-a-systemverilog-port.390303/

Particularly the comments by dave_59

Comment: Can you explain why w1 is input? w1 is sum of y and z, so I think it as output.

Comment: Changed it in the answer code to match the rest of the design.